# Best way to setup Jenkins with multiple Docker containers?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

All,

I've searched this high and low but was not able to find a reliable answer. The question may be simple for some Pro's but please help me with this...

We have a situation where we need Jenkins to be able to access and build within Docker containers. The target Docker containers are built and instantiated with a separate docker-compose. What would be the best way of connecting Jenkins with Docker containers in each scenario's as below?

**Scenario 1 :** Jenkins is setup on host machine it self. 2 Docker containers instantiated using their own docker-compose file. How can Jenkins connect to the containers in this situation? Host cannot ping Docker containers since both are on different networks (Host on Physical and Docker containers on docker DNS) hence maybe no SSH as well?

**Scenario 2 :** We prefer Jenkins to be in its own container (with its own docker-compose) so as we can replicate the same on to other environments. How can Jenkins connect to the containers in this situation? Jenkins container cannot ping Docker containers even though I use the same network in both docker-compose files. Instead it creates additional bridge network on its own e.g. from 2nd scenario below, if I have network-01 in Docker-Compose 01 and if I mention the same in Docker-Compose 2, docker creates additional network for Compose 2. As a result, I cannot ping the Node/Mongo containers from the Jenkins container (so I guess no SSH either).

Note 1 : I'm exposing 22 on both docker images i.e. Node & Mongo...
Note 2 : Our current setup has Jenkins on the host machine with exposed docker volumes from the container to the host. Is this preferred approach?

Am I missing the big elephant in the room or the solution is complicated (should'nt be!)?

[image]

Comment: No takers for this one? Docker & Jenkins experts?